# Projection maps on uncountable product are open

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be any set and let $X_\alpha$, $\alpha\in A$, be any topological space. Assuume that $X=\prod _{\alpha\in A}X_\alpha$ is provided by the weakest topology $\tau$ such that all projections $\pi_\alpha:X\to X_\alpha$, $\pi_\alpha(\{x_\alpha\}):= x_\alpha$, are continuous. This topology $\tau$ is called by the Tychonoff topology. The topological space $(X, \tau)$ is called the Tychonoff product of topological
spaces $(X_\alpha, \tau_\alpha)$ and is denoted by $(X, \tau)= \prod_{\alpha\in A}(X_\alpha, \tau_\alpha)$. Also, $\{\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(U_\alpha)| U_\alpha\in \tau_\alpha, \alpha\in A\}$  is a  basis for $X$.

I know that if $f:X\times Y\to X$ is projection map, then $f$ is open.
But, in my research, I work with projection map $\pi_\alpha: X\to X_\alpha$ where $(X, \tau)= \prod_{\alpha\in A}(X_\alpha, \tau_\alpha)$ and $A$ is uncountable.

What can say about openness of $\pi_\alpha$?

Comment: That topology has a very useful subbasis, and to check openness of one of the projections you need only check that open sets in that subbasis have open image. Can you do this?

Comment: $\{\pi^{-1}_\alpha(U_\alpha)\mid U_\alpha\in\tau_\alpha,\alpha\in A\}$ is not a basis (unless $\lvert A\rvert\le 1$): it's a subbasis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projection maps are always open, the cardinality of $A$ does not play any role.

As you say, the product topology is the weakest topology such that all projections are continuous. This means that it is weakest topology containing all $\pi^{-1}_\alpha(U_\alpha)$ with $\alpha \in A$ and $U_\alpha \in \tau_\alpha$. In other words, a *subbasis* for the product topology $\tau_p$ is given by

$$\mathcal S_p = \{\pi^{-1}_\alpha(U_\alpha) \mid \alpha \in A, U_\alpha \in \tau_\alpha \} .$$

The set of all finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal S_p$ gives then a basis $\mathcal B_p$ for $\tau_p$. Obviously we have
$$\mathcal B_p = \{\prod_{\alpha \in A}U_\alpha \mid U_\alpha \in \tau_\alpha, U_\alpha \ne X_\alpha \text{ only for finitely many } \alpha \in A \} .$$
Clearly $\pi_\alpha(\prod_{\alpha \in A}U_\alpha) = U_\alpha \in \tau_\alpha$ for all $\prod_{\alpha \in A}U_\alpha) \in \mathcal B_p$. This implies that $\pi_\alpha(U) \in \tau_\alpha$ for all $U \in \tau_p$:

Each $U \in \tau_p$ is the union of basic open sets $U_\beta$, $\beta  \in B$, so that
$$\pi_\alpha(U) = \pi_\alpha(\bigcup_{\beta \in B} U_\beta) =\bigcup_{\beta \in B}\pi_\alpha( U_\beta) \in \tau_\alpha . $$